# Converted old C++ project into VS 2010 project. Getting error

Tags: msbuild

The "CppClean" task was not given a value for the required parameter "FoldersToClean"

Answer (score 0):

There is exactly one web page in The Google that discusses this error's source, as of this writing:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee862481.aspx

It sounds like the DEVENV auto-upgrader for old workspaces, solutions, and projects does not successfully handle this old C++ project of yours.

Is there any output in the `Upgrade.XML` files relating to it?

Answer (score 0):

The *CppClean task was not given a value for the required parameter FoldersToClean* error occurs if the project's `Output Directory` or `Intermediate Directory` are empty or contain a macro that yields an empty or otherwise invalid result.

Specify `$(Configuration)` or perhaps `<inherit from parent or project defaults>` to solve this.

via [EatMyRandom Blog](http://eatmyrandom.blogspot.nl/2013/04/error-msb4044-cppclean-task-was-not.html).